# enable no form submission until recaptcha is filled-in through code behind in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, recaptcha

I am using google recaptcha for my registration page. I don't want the submission of my form until recaptcha has been verified but I want to do this from code behind using c#. How can i do so? Please leave your answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even if there is a way, it definitely isn't going to happen from code behind. The captcha is displayed in the browser, the form is also in the browser. If the solution exists, it definitely works in the browser, too.

Comment: Okay @WiktorZychla so what i should do to make it a required field?

Comment: I don't know, really. Assuming it renders client-side and is controlled by their custom script, the only chance is to find their api that makes it required upon form submission. If you find anything on your own, their implementation could as well change the very next day and your custom solution would not work.